# Prove that $\left \|x(t_0) \right \|\exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1) \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right )\le \left \| x(t) \right \|$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-inequality

I have a problem:

For $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x$, where $A(t)\in C\left [t_0,+\infty  \right )$. Prove that:
$$\left \|x(t_0)  \right \|\exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right )\le \left \| x(t) \right \|\le \left \|x(t_0)  \right \|\exp \left (\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ), \forall t \ge t_0$$
I have thought about [Bellman-Gronwall's inequality](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bellman-Gronwall_inequality#References), but I still no solution :( . Can anyone have an idea or a solution? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand these norm symbols. Is your solution vector-valued? And if so, is $A$ an operator-valued function?

Answer (score 1):

Ok! **Here's my solution:**

- Since $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x $$, $$\implies \int_{\tau}^{t}\dot{x}(t)\mathrm{d}t = \int_{\tau}^{t}A(t)x(t)\mathrm{d}t, \forall t \ge \tau \ge t_0$$ $$\implies x(t) =x(\tau)+\int_{\tau}^{t}A(t)x(t)\mathrm{d}t,\forall t \ge \tau \ge t_0\\$$
- Thus, $$\|x(t)\| =\|x(\tau)\|+\int_{\tau}^{t}\|A(t)\| \|x(t)\|\mathrm{d}t,\forall t \ge \tau \ge t_0\\$$
- Now, we apply general **Bellman-Gronwall's inequality**, we have:
  $$\left \|x(t_0)  \right \|\exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right )\le \left \| x(t) \right \|\le \left \|x(t_0)  \right \|\exp \left (\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ), \forall t \ge t_0$$

**QED**

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ln |x(t)|-\ln |x(t_0)| = \int_{t_0}^t A(t_1)dt_1.$

Comment: You mean: $$\exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right )\le \dfrac{\left \| x(t) \right \|}{\left \|x(t_0)  \right \|}\le \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ), \forall t \ge t_0$$ then $$ \int_{t_0}^{t} -\left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1  \le \ln \left ( \dfrac{\left \| x(t) \right \|}{\left \|x(t_0)  \right \|}   \right ) \le  \int_{t_0}^{t} \left \|A(t_1)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t_1$$. Hence, We have your hint? R u sure!?

Comment: I think we can use **general Bellman-Gronwall's inequality**: *If continuous function $u(t)>0$ and such that inequality: $$u(t)\le u(\tau )+\int_{\tau}^{t}f(t_1)u(t_1)\left |\mathrm{d}t_1  \right |, \forall t,\tau \in (a,b), f(t)\in C(a,b), f(t)\ge 0, a<t<b$$. Then we have: 
$$u(t_0)\exp \left ( -\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ) \le u(t) \le u(t_0)\exp \left ( \int_{t_0}^{t}f(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1 \right ), \forall a<t_0 \le t<b$$.* Can you prove that?

Comment: First of all, could you please explain what do you mean by $\|x(t)\|$? Is $x$ vector-valued?

Comment: @ **njguliyev** : Yes, It is.